# TABLE LAYOUT ANDROID

Tags: java, android, xml

Tengo la siguienta tabla con imagenes

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="#000000" />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_toolbar"
            android:background="@color/white">
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="100dp"
               android:layout_height="55dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal ="true"
               android:layout_gravity = "center"
               android:background="@mipmap/banred"
               />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#c3c3c3"/>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/white">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@mipmap/pagos"
                android:onClick="goToPayment"
                android:contentDescription="@string/menu" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@mipmap/noti"
                android:onClick="goToBillingNotifications" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:background="@color/white">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
                android:background="@mipmap/cobrar"
                android:onClick="goToBilling"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@mipmap/listacobor"
                android:onClick="goToBillingList" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:background="@color/white">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@mipmap/consulta"
                android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
                android:onClick="goToMovsMobileWallet"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@mipmap/retiro"
                android:onClick="goToCashout" />
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Tengo la altura puesta a mano 140 dp por lo que en telefonos pequeños salen cortadas cual seria la forma las optima de solucionar esto ,

utilizando

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones, primeramente puedes definir como altura "wrap_content", para que las imágenes se muestren correctamente y no se trunquen.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

o puedes definir  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` para obligar a que la imagen completa se muestre dentro del contenedor.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: muchas gracias Jorge@

Comment: Ahora que lo pruebo , con las 2 opciones queda mal , dejo arriba las capturas

Comment: Además de utilizar scaleType="fitXY", has comprobado que las imágenes tengan el tamaño correcto? Si les vas a dar la propiedad height=wrap_content cogerán su tamaño original. Hazlas más pequeñas y a la tabla que las contiene dale la propiedad que te ha dicho @Jorgesys, a ver si así te mejora

Comment: Pablo cual seria las medidas correctas de altura x ancho para HDPI MDPI XHDPI etc?

Comment: Pablo en el caso que comentas no son iconos  de launcher, tab, menu, actionbar o aplicación, debes definir medidas diferentes que sería mayores, que te parece lo doble que las del menú: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html